# Vim Error events

Tags: vim, netbeans

I am working on a [project](https://github.com/averagehat/phonim-jython) to make vim compatible with screenreaders. As part of this project, I want to capture error messages and send them to the screen-reading process (via netbeans protocol). i.e. when a user attempts to edit a file that has read-only permissions, I want to capture the message: `"E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off"`  which gets sent to the command-line window, and fire off a bit of vim script. (I also want to capture the output of ex commands, which is related). For example, I would like something like:

`:au OnError * : sendMessage()`

However, no such `"OnError"` autocommand event exists. How can I simulate such an event?

The `:redir`   command could allow me to redirect output to a buffer which is being monitored by netbeans (which would then allow me to capture the message). However, the changes are only written when `:redir END` is called. And because there are no events for errors, I would never know when to call `:redir END`.

None of the netbeans events (listed [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/netbeans.html#nb-events) ) offer any obvious help.

I know I can send the history via `:messages`, but this doesn't help a user who needs to immediately know about errors they've caused. And there are [problems](https://news.floobits.com/2013/09/16/adding-realtime-collaboration-to-vim/) with trying to hack an event-loop into vim.

I have considered [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) but we want something that is totally cross-platform (gvim for windows). I am also concerned about their compatibility with other scripts and neovim's continued support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Error event means no generic way to listen/capture generic errors. To capture an error within a user-defined vim function, do the following:

The safest solution would be — just like in any other programming language — to wrap your commands in a `try|catch|endtry` construction:

```
function! InsertFoo()
    try
        norm Ifoo
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E21/
        call SendMessage(v:exception, v:errmsg)
    endtry
endfunction
```

The function above will insert `foo` at the beginning of the current line in a writable buffer but throw an `E21` exception when called in a read-only buffer (`:help` for example) and allow you to call your hypothetical `SendMessage()` (here with the error message and the full exception as arguments, use the one you prefer) that would presumably be in charge of displaying that information to your user.

Reference:

```
:help exception-handling
:help :try
:help :catch
:help v:errmsg
:help v:exception
:help errors
:help <errornumber>
```

Comment: The problem is I want to catch all errors, not just ones produced by the functions I write. A user could cause `E21` by using `dd`, `p`, `O`, the list goes on. Is it possible to wrap built-in functionality or groups of functions?

Comment: No `Error` event means no generic way to listen/capture generic errors, plain and simple. You could try a loop, maybe using `CursorMoved` in Vim or whatever you can use in your host program, and watch `v:exception` for a change.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. I can at least capture errors and messages (using `:messages` and the like). Is their a way to get recent command output (e.g. the result of `:echo "foo"`) without using `:redir` ?

Comment: Also, is there a reason no such OnError event exists? i.e. is it feasible to add that event without too much fuss? From what I can tell browsing through vim's source, it looks feasible, but there may be hidden problems . . .

Comment: Vim's source code is a minefield and its development process is very conservative. If you feel like doing it I won't complain but don't expect your patch to be widely available soon.